# How to show a dialog in android on navigating to another activity for the first time?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

How to show a dialog in android on navigating to another activity only for the first time?  I dont want to put it in the onResume() of the activity because then the dialog shows up each and every time i navigate to that activity.

Comment: Use `SharedPreferrence` to check first time navigation and show dialog when you do navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this finction in onCreate handler

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    if (isFirstTime()) {
        // show dialog
    }
    ...
}


/***
 * Checks that application runs first time and write flag at SharedPreferences 
 * @return true if 1st time
 */
private boolean isFirstTime()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    if (!ranBefore) {
        // first time
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
    return !ranBefore;
}
```

Comment: if this awnser is right can you accept it then please :)